# Проблема с расширением Xupload в Yii

Tags: php, yii

Уже несколько дней парюсь над этой проблемой.

После выбора файла(ов) и нажатия на кнопку "Start" в тэге со стилем 'error' вылезает следующее сообщение: "Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". Я использую Google Chrome, работаю на Ubuntu. Установил расширение по инструкции, не менял никаких файлов самого расширения.

Гуглил. Облазил если не все, то большую часть форумов и статей, в которых упоминается эта ошибка и пришёл к умозаключению, что вся проблема в тэгах <script> в файлах 'download.php' и 'upload.php'. Но что с этим делать дальше - не знаю.

Да, я пробовал выносить скрипт между этими тэгами в отдельные файлы, результат не меняется.

Помогите советом пожалуйста, ибо запарился разбираться. Кроме того, это самое работоспособное расширение для работы с файлами, которое я нашёл.

P. S. Если у кого-то есть опыт подключения elFinder в Yii, поделитесь пожалуйста.

**UPD** Как меня заверил разработчик расширения, ошибок в этих файлах быть не должно и теги <script> не должны мешать работе скрипта. Вот сами файлы:
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2RDfZTgMPVpRWtTUG9scUNNWEk (upload.php),
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2RDfZTgMPVpRWtTUG9scUNNWEk (download.php).

Comment: Всё, решил проблему - нашёл рабочее расширение elFinder, подключил, всё замечательно. Если кому-то надо, держите: https://bitbucket.org/z_bodya/yii-elfinder

Answer (score 1):

Ну если ругается на

> Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Значит все-таки ошибка в синтаксисе. Выложи куда нить эти файлы для просмотра. Иначе тут ничего не понятно.

> P. S. Если у кого-то есть опыт
> подключения elFinder в Yii, поделитесь
> пожалуйста.

[yii forum](http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8159)

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Спасибо за ссылку на тему форума.